# Qt Action Dropdown Widget

Tags: user-interface, qt

I am creating a drawing application where the user can insert primitive shapes, like circles, triangles, etc.  In the toolbar, I would like to have a single "Add Shape" button that shows a dropdown widget when pressed.  In the dropdown, I would like to have a grid of QAction icons representing the different shapes the user can add.  This is almost identical to how one adds basic shapes in powerpoint.

I know how to create a dropdown menu using a QToolButton and setMenu.  However, this lists actions in a traditional menu format.  I want the QActions showing only their icons, and to have them arranged in a grid - like a toolbar that has multiple rows.  Do I have to create a custom widget for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default QMenu uses a vertical layout to display the QActions so If you want a grid you need to subclass it to create your custom one.